# Working with config files as objects in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I didn't want to use and passing arrays within controllers and views, and after a really code mess I figured out that create an object could save my day.

I'm not very skilled with objects but after many proofs and errors (who doesn't?) I get this:

---

### application/**config**/events.php:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['gallery']['general_folder'] = 'gallery';
$config['gallery']['user_folder']    = 'thumb';
```

### application/**controller**/events.php:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Events extends CI_Controller
{
  var $gallery;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->config->load('events', TRUE);
    $this->gallery = (object)$this->config->item('gallery', 'events');
  }

  public function index()
  {
     $thumb = $this->gallery->user_folder; // 'thumb'
  }
}
```

### application/**views**/events.php:

```
echo $this->gallery->general_folder; // output: gallery
```

---

The question is: Is(are) there a(n) (un)documented way to convert this kind of arrays to objects following a CodeIgniter's best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your controller class must be named exactly as the file (but capitalized)! Also best practice in CI is not to echo from the controller but to load a view.

Comment: @jtheman Oops! sorry, it was translated from my application for a better example, edited.

Comment: you can directly access those two configs by `$this->config->config['gallery']['general_folder']` and `$this->config->config['gallery']['user_folder']`. Codeigniter itself does not follow best practices though. Your method is valid too.